# How to merge an array of arrays together into a single array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following array

```
[["convertible", "2010", "red"], ["convertible", "2010", "green"]]
```

How do I merge the above array into this, in either in Rails or in Ruby?

```
["convertible", "2010", "red", "convertible", "2010", "green"]
```

**Edit-1**

```
@category.each do |content|
      form_chain = JSON.parse(content.content)
      chained_array << form_chain.values
    end

    chained_array
```

This gives the output

```
[["convertible", "2010", "red"], ["convertible", "2010", "green"]]
```

If I use `chained_array.flatten!` it gives the same result.

Comment: When in doubt, check the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[["convertible", "2010", "red"], ["convertible", "2010", "green"]].flatten!
```

Comment: It is working in my console but why it is not working in my rails application

Comment: got it some cache problem i cleared `rake tmp:clear` now working

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit you could just create a flat array from the beginning:

```
@category.each do |content|
      form_chain = JSON.parse(content.content)
      chained_array.push(*form_chain.values)
end
```